# Typo3 tt_news how to change relatedByCategory news list order

Tags: typo3

I have a website developed in Typo3 and in a page I show a news with tt_news ext in single view mode. This news has also a list of other related news obtained with the property showRelatedNewsByCategory.
The list is correctly show but I would like to revert the order of listed news, from descending to ascending but I found no way to do it.

Does anyone have any clue or suggestion?

Bests,
Nik

Answer (score 0):

```
listOrderBy = asc
```

This should work. There are also many options available e.g. sorting by title oder date. [tt_news config reference](http://typo3.org/documentation/document-library/extension-manuals/tt_news/3.0.1/view/1/4/#id2506939)

Comment: Hi I thought the same, but the order of the list doesn't change whatever I put in or wherever I set that property (site template, ext+ template or tt_news object).

Comment: make sure to delete cache. How is your plugin inserted in TS?

Comment: I use templavoila, the pluign is inserted as single view with specified in the plugin ts (under Other Settings) the showRelatedNewsByCategory = 1. I cleared the "orderby" and "Asc/DEsc" field as they say it could make some problems. I cleared all website cache, but no results. I don't really know whereelse i can look for it, I went through many times the whole Object explorer in the hope of finding any clue but nothing...

Comment: Well I would try to configure it with getRelatedCObject (). See manual example, that explains it very good.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions Rito, but I'va already tried also this path and brought me to nothing, the list does not change its order whatever I do. I tried exactly as it is on the manual but no result at all. I really don't kow what's wrong with it.

Comment: Well I'm sorry, I'm running out of ideas.

Comment: Don't feel alone, no problem. I think I'll go for a jQuery solution for the moment... till I get an inspiration.

Comment: I usually try to add a line  `t3lib_div::debug($this->conf);` to the .php file (in this case class.tx_ttnews.php) to see how the extension is configured during runtime. Sometimes there's typo, sometimes your setup get's overridden. And sometimes it's a bug that should be filed.